# CSS triangle up and down have different alignment in Firefox

Tags: firefox, cross-browser, browser-testing, css

I'm trying to make an image-less icon for a drop down menu using CSS triangles that point up and down. Code looks like this: http://jsfiddle.net/FGrR2/6/

```
.d, .u {
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  border-style: solid;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.d {
  border-width: 5px 5px 0 5px;
  border-color: #007bff transparent transparent transparent;
}
.u {   
  border-width: 0 5px 5px 5px;
  border-color: transparent transparent #007bff transparent;
}
```

However, if I load the page in Firefox 17.0.1, the edges of the triangles don't line up. Here's a zoomed version of how that looks: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LzTrN.jpg It's like the 2nd triangle is "aligned" to the right or something.

Has anyone else encountered this?

Comment: Not sure if this will help you but the triangles are perfectly aligned in Firefox 21.0(latest version).

Comment: They are not aligned in Firefox 21.0 for me (MAC)

Comment: Probably not what your looking for but if you add margin-left:-1px to .d it will fix it

Comment: @PaulRadich but wouldn't that mis-align them in other browsers?

Comment: You would have to test that. I did not come across a browser where it was aligned. Only browser testing will answer that.